# Arranging CollectionView cells with UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Need to make cells appear larger

Tags: ios, swift

I am arranging collection view cells in a grid similar to the one pictured with 3 cells across, although each item appears smaller than I would like. I used the code below to achieve what is pictured, as the goal is to make it display this grid across most phone devises in portrait mode.

How can I make the items appear larger, but still keep 3 across?

Question is answered, thanks! For anyone having the same issue, make sure to use this method: *collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)*.

```
let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.inset(by: collectionView.layoutMargins).width
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: availableWidth/3, height: availableWidth/3)

layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 30

collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

[image: Example of grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cellInRow = 3
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(cellInRow - 1))
    let mySize = collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace
    let size = mySize / CGFloat(cellInRow)

    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to account for additional interitem spacing while calculating `availableWidth` as in following example.

```
let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 3
let minimumSpacing: CGFloat = 10

let spacing = ((numberOfColumns - 1) * minimumSpacing)
let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.inset(by: collectionView.layoutMargins).width - spacing

let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: availableWidth/numberOfColumns, height: availableWidth/numberOfColumns)

layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumSpacing
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 30

collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove line spacing value from your hight and width of cell

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.size.width - 90
        let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.frame.size.hight
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/3, height: collectionViewHeight/3 + ((collectionViewHeight/3)))
    }
```